# is it possible to add a few empty lists to each newly created cloud firestore user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'll start with an example:
a user has it's login credentials and a list which contains the id's from the movies he likes and a list with the movie id's he dislikes. These are all stored in the firebase cloud firestore.

To achieve the example above i would like to add 2 empty lists whenever a user creates an account so i can then add data to the lists later on.

From what i've read it seems like the .set() method should work but i just wanted to verify it with u guys here before i continue.

I don't know if this may be of any help but this is what i would like to have as result (green stuff added):
[result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF7RV.png)

I'm not an English speaker so if i need to clarify something please let me know in the comments.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can add lists of information you want when you create a document in Firestore.  The lists can be empty - that's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!